# Android get Frame dp dimension

Tags: android, layout, dimension

Any way to get layout (frame, linear ...) in dp? My FrameLayout is set to be wrap content so I calculate dimension of items inside to get the dimension but I am not sure about the reliability; any solution? Thanks in advance

Comment: You can maybe use the depricated methods `.getWidth` or `.getHeight` to do this. There is likely a better way but I can't think of it off of the top of my head. Do some research into it. I believe this has been answered before. Good luck!

Comment: @BenyamEphrem It is impossible. My layout is set as "wrap_content" if I use fill_parent/match_parent/wrap_content  the method .getWidth will never return dp dimension but -2 or 0 (or other values I don't remember)

Answer (score 1):

do this like below code

```
int height = yourLayout.getLayoutParams().getHeight;
int width = yourLayout.getLayoutParams().getWidth;
```

It will give you height, width in pixel

**Carefull**

Write this code after your layour(views) created successfully, Otherwise it will return 0.

Now convert this px to dp by using the following method

```
public int pxToDp(int px) {
    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    int dp = Math.round(px / (displayMetrics.xdpi / DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT));
    return dp;
}
```